# GreenDao set entity property by column name

Tags: android, greendao

I have an entity with 500 properties, each of those have human redeable names like 'serialNumber', but it's column_name is 'E_A_XNF'.

Now I have a form which gives me a Map with the column name as a key.

How can I, with GreenDao, do something like :

```
String columnName = 'E_A_XNF';
String serialNumber = myMap.get(columnName);
entity.setByColumnName(columnName, serialNumber);
```

obviously in the real program I will loop over every entry in the map.

Thanks.

## EDIT :

I have this entity :

```
@Entity(nameInDb = "T_REF_CHAMP", generateConstructors = false,
        indexes = {@Index(value = "id", unique = true)})
public class ChampEntity {

    @Property(nameInDb = "ID_DAO")
    @Id
    private Long idDAO;

    @Property(nameInDb = "ID_CHAM")
    @NotNull
    private String id;

    @Property(nameInDb = "TAILLE_MAX_CHAM")
    private String tailleMaximum;

    @Property(nameInDb = "TYPE_CODE_CHAM")
    private String typeCode;

    @Property(nameInDb = "VAL_DEFAUT_CHAM")
    private String defaultValue;

    //more than 500 other property
    //more than 500 other property
    //more than 500 other property
    //more than 500 other property
    //more than 500 other property
    //more than 500 other property
    //more than 500 other property

    //getter setter

    }
```

then I have this :

```
Map<String, String> dataToStore = new Hashmap<>();
dataToStore.put(ID_CHAM, "qzdqzddqzd");
dataToStore.put(TAILLE_MAX_CHAM, "122");
dataToStore.put(TYPE_CODE_CHAM, "lolola");
dataToStore.put(VAL_DEFAUT_CHAM, "ergot");
//more than 500 other values
```

How do I fill the entity with this map? since the entity only contains the column real names.

Comment: This problem is for retrieving and mapping the row in the DB with the entity in a fast way?

Comment: it's for filling the entity without having to write each set by hand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is using the reflection.

```
//example class
public class TestEntity {
    @Property(nameInDb = "NAME")
    public String name;

    @Property(nameInDb = "SURNAME")
    public String surname;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TestEntity{" +
               "name='" + name + '\'' +
               ", surname='" + surname + '\'' +
               "}";
    }
}

//example map
Map<String, String> dataStore = new HashMap<>();
dataStore.put("NAME", "mat");
dataStore.put("SURNAME", "pag");

//use reflection to fill object
TestEntity te = new TestEntity();
Field[] fields = te.getClass().getFields();
for (Field field : fields) {
    //search the field for the GreenDao Property annotation
    Property propertyAnnot = field.getAnnotation(Property.class);
    if (propertyAnnot != null) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> pair : dataStore.entrySet()) {
            //match the map key and the nameInDb value
            if (pair.getKey().equals(propertyAnnot.nameInDb())) {
                try {
                    field.set(te, pair.getValue());
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

//check the values of the filled object
te.toString();
```

Obviously this is not performance optimized but you can do it yourself based on your logic.

Comment: I'd like to do it without making a query, by manipulating the entity only.

Comment: Sorry but i think what you want to achieve it's a bit unclear or you are using the wrong terms to refers to some entity of OOP. With the solution i posted you should be able to fill/retrieve your objects and save/query them automatically without handling the column mapping complexity to the DB (which greenDao is used for)

Comment: you misunderstood my need, or I explain it badly, I will edit my main post

Comment: ok i've understood what you are trying to do now, but why you can't simply do `champEntity.property = value;` and so on for every property? Why you need a map for setting up the values?

Comment: the map is being return by an other program which I do not control, I'm looking for a way to do this without having to write myself entity.setXXX(map.get(yyy) 500 times (this is not the only entity I will have to fill :/).

Comment: Ok, finally you explained where the map is coming from :D. I could have a solution for you but currently i'm unable to work on it. I will do when i'll go back to home

Comment: Thanks you very much :D

Comment: well I explored all the documentation, it looks like it's just not possible

Comment: Have you tried with my edited answer? i've updated it 3 days ago as promised. I've tested it and it worked

Comment: I did not saw it before no, I never thought about using reflection, I was only thinking of using greenDao functionality, this would indeed work, thanks.

Comment: @sliders_alpha pls mark it as the correct answer. gl :)